# a high turnover (rate)

Tags: ambiguity

The word *turnover* at least has two meanings in the dictionary. Without context, is the following sentence ambiguous?

The company has a high turnover.

Supposing it's ambiguous, if the word *rate* is inserted at the end, is it still ambiguous? I'm entertaining only two possibilities here: the company receives substantial revenues, or many employees come and go.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: As written I think most people would choose "many employees come and go". Though as you say, there is more than one definition. *rate* just quantifies either one over time (employees vs. money).

Answer (score 1):

In England at least *turnover* means the total income a company receives in a year (or given time period). *Turnover rate* is definitely ambiguous and it would be better to use something like "weekly turnover" or "daily turnover". Basically, without a time period it is ambiguous. *Turnover* on its own is not ambiguous but it would definitely be improved with a time period.